# I can see the file on the server however I cannot use "get" comand on it (putty/psftp)

Tags: tar, putty, psftp

I am new to using these sftp programs to get files from a server so understand that I might be very ignorant to a lot of things. With that being said:

I am using windows command line to run psftp.exe like so:

`psftp.exe hostname@server -i "myprivatekey.ppk"`

the prompt takes me successfully to the server. From here I navigate to the directory I want. I use "ls" command to see all files under the directory.
I see my file which is some tar file that is in the format "somestuff.DSD.tar.somenumber" 
I type:
`get somestuff.DSD.tar.somenumber`

The prompt then tells me:
`/somedirectory/somestuff.DSD.tar.somenumber:open for read: no such file or directory`

What is the problem here? why does it not see the file? is it the .tar file with the extention of somenumber after tar ? I am not sure what a tar file is I believe some zipped folder that stores multiple files.

Thank you for your time and looking into this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The prompt then tells me: /somedirectory/somestuff.DSD.tar.somenumber:open for read: no such file or directory

At a guess you either mistyped the file name - or psftp is not in the right directory to get the file.

does  `ls *.tar.*` list the file your need to get?

Tar files are just archive files - and in Unix operating systems the file extension does not determine the file type.  By default tar files are not compressed `zipped` but they can be compressed so save space.

hth

Comment: That is helpful about the unix file extentions, thanks!
when i do `ls *.tar.*` i do see my file. I also used get using somestuff* which would only pick out that file and nothing else. I did this incase I had a typo.

Comment: Was the error message still: open for read: no such file or directory? as my other guess would be file permissions - but the error message then is usually: open for read: permission denied

Comment: The other thing to check is wether when you type `lpwd` it shows the a directory on your windows machine that you can write too - otherwise psftp will fail.  To change the local directory type `lcd /path/to/direcory`. Can you get any of the files in the directory? `mget *` will get all files on the remote server.

Comment: thanks fcbsd it worked now. I tried all your suggestions but it seemed to work after I used `mget file_name_prefix.*` Could it be tar files are seen as multiple files hence we have to use mget instead of the regular get?